# Getting data from device browser from a native android app

Tags: java, android, cookies, local-storage, webapp2

I have two seperate applications, one is a web app and other is a native android application. I would like to know is there a way to communicate to the web app from the android application. Basically i need to get some value returned from the web app to my native application. I cannot use a webview as both need to be separate application.
Can I access the localstorage of the browser from my native app ? I can store the value that i need in a localstorage and get that in my native app ..
Or can i access the browser cookie from native app ?

Please let me know, is there any way of communication between native and web app. Again, both are separate apps. So no scope of using web view.

Appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Any idea whether this is possible????

Comment: Looking for the same, but I need data FROM the native to the web browser.
Ill make an update if I find anything